# Tried everything but still cannot serve static files of Django project via nginx+gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have to deploy Django project via nginx+gunicorn(static files by nginx and other files by gunicorn.)

dev.py file inside settings folder of the project have these settings -

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

nginx.conf looks like this -

```
server {
listen 8000;   
server_name  localhost;

access_log /home/user/access.log;
error_log /home/user/error.log;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
}

location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/user/project_revamped/project/static;
}

}
```

I am running my server as -

```
gunicorn project.wsgi:application --bind=127.0.0.1:8001
```

On accessing server at URL at localhost:8001, page shows up without any static files.

The error.log of nginx does not get populated. The error is that browser is trying to request static files from url

```
localhost:8001/static/...
```

however it should request files from URL -

```
localhost:8000/static/...
```

as nginx is configured to serve through that url.

Comment: Do you need a / at the end of the alias dir path ?

Comment: Your conf file serves static files on port 8000 but you are trying to reach them on port 8001. This did not make sense to me.

Comment: @paradoksumsu - what should I change then? nginx works like this.If request is on path / , it delegates to gunicorn server and if the path is /static then nginx handles it.

Comment: run this: `gunicorn project.wsgi:application --bind=127.0.0.1:8000` instead of that `gunicorn project.wsgi:application --bind=127.0.0.1:8001`

Comment: @paradoksumsu - not working still

Comment: have you tried to run `python manage.py collectstatic` ?

Comment: @paradoksumsu - yupp already did that

Comment: try that, `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static','static-only')` and create a directory in the same dir with `static`. Also delete auto index from nginx conf and add a '/' to and of the file path for static, add this `location /static-only/ {
alias /home/user/project_revamped/project/static-only/;
}` and then restart nginx server and then try collectstatic again. This should work.

Comment: @paradoksumsu - you are creating here static-only folder inside the static folder if I am not wrong? But why location /static-only/? I guess STATIC_DIR is '/static/' so it should be location /static/.

Comment: Sorry, I just copied it from mine. It should be `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static-only')`

Comment: @paradoksumsu - dude but server is serving at the path 'static' and not 'static-only' so it should be location /static/

Comment: I understood that. I don't know why but this does work in my server. So I think, this maybe works for you too.

Comment: This all I have for you. Sorry about that.

Comment: @paradoksumsu - I also tried your method but it did not work for me.

Comment: permissions. I bet you dont have proper permission on the directory with statics, so nginx cant access them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
server {
  listen 8000;   
  server_name  localhost;
  root /home/user/project_dir/project;

  access_log /home/user/access.log;
  error_log /home/user/error.log;

  location /static/ {
    alias /home/user/project_dir/project/static/;
  }
  location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
      proxy_redirect default;
  }
```

- i think this should be correct configuration for your case.
- ideally you should listen all the http request on port 80 ,so listen
  8000 shall be changed to 80 in production.
- if you write location / before and static things after code would
  never reach the location /static/
- there must be "proxy_set_header Host $http_host;" so that in debug=
  False (in production) allowed host gets some value